# Adding proxy support to existing application...?

Tags: .net, http, proxy

I'm wondering if it's possible (and how) to build a tool to add support for proxy connection to an existing application. Let me explain.

Take the CodePlex Client (cpc.exe), it's a command line utility used to connect to CodePlex TFS. I'm behind a proxy and not being able to use it. I'd like to write an application, let's say "ProxyEnabler". This application will launch the cpc.exe file as a child process and intercept each HTTP request to rebuild it with a proxy configuration.

It can be used like this: ProxyEnabler.exe cpc.exe 
It can read the proxy configuration in an app.config file.

I don't ask here to write the application ;-) I just need to know if it feasible (mainly the HTTP interception & redirection)

Answer (score -1):

[FreeCap](http://www.freecap.ru/eng) can do this (proxies via HTTP CONNECT or Socks), but it works by hooking the Windows socket functions; I'm not sure how to do that in .net

Comment: Thanks for the link but it's unusable for my issue.

Comment: Crashes with my C# app... any alternatives (free)?